# django - send image back to http response without saving the image

Tags: django

I want to create a preview image before the actual form upload.  I have a preview button for the user to first look at the photo before submitting it.  Once the use clicks the preview button, what is the best way in django to respond with an image without actually saving the image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a file-like such as `StringIO` to the [`HttpResponse`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) constructor that contains the image data.

Comment: thanks ignacio, do you recommend i go this route or save it in a temp file first and go the traditional route with a url?

Comment: That completely depends on whether or not you'll ever need the image again.